# How to edit a box so that it's not selected when clicking inside it?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

How to edit a box so that it's not selected when clicking inside it?

(I can still select it by clicking its edge.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been searching for a long time and can't find a way.

Later, when I was testing randomly on my own, I found a way.

1. Set the two graphics as a group,
   [image]
2. Then display the group lines,
   [image]
3. Then delete the two graphics in the group.

**Attention !** When deleting, only click on those two graphics, do not click on       the outer frame.
[image]
Deng Deng~

You get a perfect outer frame. Clicking the area inside the outer frame will not let the outer frame be clicked.

You can change the line to a dotted line and then put it in scratchpad for next time use.   (^.^)
[image]

Comment: Well, that was certainly clever! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, but I was searching for an answer. I searched and fiddled around and for me the **Pointer Events** do the trick. You can find it under Style of the object.
[image: Nested rectangles]

This makes the outer rectangle selectable only by clicking on the actual line. And makes the internal rectangle selectable even if background.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that a lot of shapes do not have this property

Comment: So it is connected to the fill property (checkbox). If its not selected, the Pointer Events property is visible.

Answer (score 1):

If the shape is transparent to clicks you can right-click the perimeter and select "edit", or press either `F2` or `Enter` while the shape is selected to start editing.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked.

Comment: Please clarify the question, it isn't clear in its current form.

Comment: I want to be able to click inside a shape, without selecting it. For example, if I use a rectangle ("Line" selected, "Fill" deselected" ) to enclose other shapes, I want to be able to click inside the perimeter of that rectangle, and the rectangle itself is not selected. You say "If the shape is transparent to clicks"... I _want_ the shape to be transparent to clicks: how do I do that? Unselecting "fill: does not do that.